# Insert _Post response into avariable

Tags: php, search, post, get

Search page looks like this

```
<form method="post" action="response.php">
    <input type="text" name="varianta" value="var_varianta">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
session_start();
$var_varianta= $_POST['varianta'];
  ?>
```

The response page has the below line code:

```
 $filters[] = array("filterType" => "resultLimit", "filterValue" => "varianta");
```

How i can i enter tn the  `"filterValue" => "**varianta**");` the $var_varianta that is inputed in the search field

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're asking, but it seems like there's some confusion. `$_POST` contains the values that have been submitted, not the values that a user is entering. So, `$_POST` variables are set on the action page, not on the page showing the form. You can't set a `$_POST` variable in PHP on the page showing the form and expect the action page to know about that.

If I understand your question correctly, you should use `$_POST['varianta']` on the action page to access whatever was submitted.